# ERRO SYNTAX WHERE - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho o seguinte código em php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM musicas_curtidas 
    GROUP BY musica 
    ORDER BY count(musica) 
    WHERE musica != 'Rádio Turn - Você em primeiro lugar!' AND
    WHERE musica != 'Radio Turn - Não importa o seu estilo! #2' AND
    WHERE musica != 'Radio Turn - Não importa o seu estilo!' AND
    WHERE musica != 'Rádio Turn - Comercial' AND
    WHERE musica != 'Rádio Turn - Na Balada'
    DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Está me retornando um erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE musica != 'Rádio Turn - Você em primeiro lugar!' AND ' at line 4

Como posso resolver isso? Sou novato em php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, PHP não tem nada a ver com o assunto, esse é um erro de SQL.

- A cláusula Where é uma só
- O Agrupamento depois
- O Order vem depois
- E o limite no fim

Se tiver dúvidas ao montar uma *query*, o Manual é uma boa referência, mesmo caso não tenha facilidade em inglês, tem os exemplos e descrição da sintaxe já na ordem certa:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Provavelmente teria como melhorar a lógica usada, mas pelo que pôs na pergunta, esses 4 pontos seriam os primeiros a resolver.

```
SELECT *

FROM  musicas_curtidas 

WHERE musica != 'Rádio Turn - Você em primeiro lugar!'
      AND musica != 'Radio Turn - Não importa o seu estilo! #2'
      AND musica != 'Radio Turn - Não importa o seu estilo!'
      AND musica != 'Rádio Turn - Comercial' 
      AND musica != 'Rádio Turn - Na Balada'

GROUP BY musica 

ORDER BY count(musica) DESC

LIMIT 3
```

Poderia simplificar para

```
SELECT *

FROM  musicas_curtidas 

WHERE musica NOT IN (
   'Rádio Turn - Você em primeiro lugar!',
   'Radio Turn - Não importa o seu estilo! #2',
   'Radio Turn - Não importa o seu estilo!',
   'Rádio Turn - Comercial',
   'Rádio Turn - Na Balada'
)

GROUP BY musica 

ORDER BY count(musica) DESC

LIMIT 3
```

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho perfeito, se tiver alguma duvida extra, só comentar (ou se for algo de assunto separado, abrir uma nova pergunta)

Comment: É possivel adicionar um WHERE para outra coluna? Por exemplo, WHERE imagem NOT IN ('...'), as duas ao mesmo tempo, musica e imagem.

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho pode fazer as combinações que quiser, mas com um WHERE só. Exemplo: `SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE nota IN ( "a", "b", "c") AND aluno_nome = "Roberto";` Ou seja, vai trazer somente quando o nome for Roberto e a nota a, b ou c